# Matching 2 out of 3 terms in Sunspot and WebSolr

Tags: solr, full-text-search, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr, websolr

THe partial matching on my search is not working correctly. When I type in "Dublin Ireland" into my search then it correctly returns all the results in Dublin, Ireland. However, when I type "County Dublin Ireland" then it doesn't return any.

I've set up an EdgeNGramFilter in my schmea.xml like so:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10"/>
```

And I'm doing a fulltext search on the sunspot end on location:

```
search_results = Events.solr_search do
  fulltext location do
    fields(:address)
  end
end
```

How come I'm getting no results even though 2 out of the 3 terms match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Sunspot uses the DisMax Query Parser, and supports a `minimum_match` method within the `fulltext` block.

```
search_results = Events.solr_search do
  fulltext location do
    fields :address
    minimum_match 2
  end
end
```

See also:

- [Stack Overflow - Solr Sunspot minimum_match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341982/154694)
- [Stack Overflow - Rails 3 Sunspot Fulltext Search Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12062436/154694)
- [Solr Wiki - DisMax query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin)
- [Websolr Blog - How do I query with boolean logic using Sunspot?](http://blog.websolr.com/post/1299174416/how-do-i-query-with-boolean-logic-using-sunspot)