# How to return search results in Sunspot Solr (rails) where not all tokens are present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot-rails

I'm running **Sunspot Solr** in my rails app. I am using it to enable a user to search for different "articles" by using fulltext search on the `:name` attribute. At this point in time, I have Sunspot Solr configured and it's working nicely.

However, when I search for `dog mouse cat` (as an example), it only returns articles that contain **all** of the keywords. How can I configure Solr to show articles like 'The dog and the cat' - which contains only 2 of the 3 search keywords in the query example above?

My `searchable` block in the model:

```
searchable do
    text :name
end
```

My current `schema.xml` **for fulltext search** looks like this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: maybe with a block in text, unfortunately documentation is not clear about it.

Comment: or maybe with `Model.search{ any_of { keywords 'dog'; keywords 'mouse' ...}}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching 2 out of 3 terms in Sunspot and WebSolr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246670/matching-2-out-of-3-terms-in-sunspot-and-websolr)

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.search do
  fulltext text do
    fields :name
    minimum_match 2
  end
end
```